# nested joins vs side by side joins

Tags: sql

imagine that you have three tables:

- target: with these columns

  - id
  - other_tb_id (foreign key)
  - other none foreign key columns
- other_tb: with these columns:

  - id
  - other_tb2_id (foreign key)
  - some_col_deleted
  - other none foreign key columns
- other_tb2: with these columns:

  - id
  - other none foreign key columns

1- now is there any difference between these two join queries (performance, readability and etc):

```
select * from target_tb
    inner join (
        select * from other_tb where some_col_deleted = false
    ) other_tb on target_tb.other_tb_id = other_tb.id
    inner join other_tb2 on other_tb.other_tb2.id = other_tb2.


select * from target_tb
    inner join (
        select * from other_tb
           inner join other_tb2 on other_tb.other_tb2.id = other_tb2.id where some_col_deleted = false
    ) other_tb on target_tb.other_tb_id = other_tb.id
```

2- I also have this question that does it have any differences if I put `where` clause outside of the inner join?

Comment: Performance questions are usually product specific, since different products optimize in different ways.

Comment: As far as performance goes, [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Readability is very personal.

Comment: @jarlh I usually work with `mariadb`, but if you know the answer please say it for both mariadb and `sql server` (2016 sp1)

Comment: @HoneyBadger here, we work as a team so we have to consider readability for later developers and development

Comment: @jarlh what about number 2? do you have any idea about it?

Comment: I would get rid of the useless parentheses and derived tables completely and simply the statement to `from target_tb join other_tb on ... join other_tb2 on ...` Those those derived tables will not improve performance at all (especially not with SQL Server) - they only make the statement harder to read.

Comment: SQL is "declarative".  The actual executed code is not the SQL you write *(like "imperative" languages)*.  You should write the code than most cleanly expresses the ***functionality / logic*** that you require, then look at execution plans / explain plans *(DBMS specific)* to see which parts of the execution warrant performance optimisation.

Comment: Unrelated, but: last time I checked, neither MariaDB nor SQL Server supported a real boolean datatype so `where some_col_deleted = false` is invalid in both products

Comment: I tested the similar queries with booleans and had no problem. I think in some phase before execution they translated to 0 and 1 @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would normally write these queries as:

```
select . . .
from target_tb t inner join
     other_tb o
     on t.other_tb_id = o.id inner join
     other_tb2 o2
     on o2.other_tb2.id = o2.?
where o.some_col_deleted = false;
```

Performance of the different versions should be pretty similar across different databases.  Part of running a query is the optimization phase.

Note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: since comments are saying the same thing and you mentioned the optimization phase, so I think I have to take it as the answer. tnx